# How to clear navigation history in a frame when using the window Current page as a view model Property for a window View Model

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio

I am making a WPF application for sales.
What I want to do is to navigate to diffrent views while choosing whether I keep the navigation history (in case I want to keep a temporary instance of a transaction) or remove one or all history of navigation (in case I want to validate all temporary transactions)
for example, I have a page transaction
there is the case where I want to keep other instances of that page open temperarly or remove all instances if I am done with one or all transaction.
I made a mainwindow that contain a frame .
I want to navigate to a diffrent page inside the frame when a button is clicked while also choosing to keep or remove the navigation history.
What I did so far was implement a window view model class and create a property (PageView) that is a enum that I can convert to the page view I want to show.

The pageview enum

```
public enum PageView
{
    Main=0,
    SecondPage=1
}
```

The converter from property PageView to the page I want to show

```
public class PageConverter : BaseCoverter<PageConverter>
{
    public override object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        switch ((PageView)value)
        {
            
            default: Debugger.Break();
                return null;
            case PageView.Main:
                return new MainPage();
            case PageView.SecondPage:
                return new SecondoryPage();
        }
    }

    public override object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

}

Main window view model

```
class WindowVM:BaseViewModel
{
    private Window VWindow;
    private PageView _pageView= PageView.Main;
    public WindowVM(Window window)
    {
        VWindow = window; 
        SwitchView = new RelayCommand(_SwitchView, _CheckButton);
    }       
    public PageView CurrentPage
    {
        set
        {
            _pageView = value;
            OnPropertyChanged(); 
        }
        get { return _pageView; ; }
    }
    public ICommand SwitchView { get; set; }

    private void _SwitchView()
    {
        ((WindowVM)((MainWindow)Application.Current.MainWindow).DataContext).CurrentPage = PageView.SecondPage;
    }

    private bool _CheckButton(object parameter)
    {
        return true;
    }
}
```

What I have right now is a frame that create a new page each time the command SwitchView is used.
What I want is to choose whether I want to be able to clear the history of the pages I navigated if i wanted to.

I found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2285122/prevent-wpf-frame-from-storing-history-in-the-stack) but I don't want to use code behind to do that.
I also found [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8585519/how-to-clear-whole-navigation-history-hosted-by-the-wpf-frame-control) but I really didn't know how to implement it.

Comment: You can use [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Navigation_NavigationService_RemoveBackEntry) to remove the most recent journal entry from back history.You can refer to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6488787/9862794) to get using of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just wrap the solution with [NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.navigation.navigationservice.removebackentry?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0#System_Windows_Navigation_NavigationService_RemoveBackEntry) method in the behavior/attached property and apply it to your Frame in xaml.

```
<Frame local:FrameNoHistoryBehavior.Enable="True" />
```

And:

```
public static class FrameNoHistoryBehavior
{
    public static bool GetEnable(DependencyObject obj)
    {
        return (bool)obj.GetValue(EnableProperty);
    }

    public static void SetEnable(DependencyObject obj, bool value)
    {
        obj.SetValue(EnableProperty, value);
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Enable.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty EnableProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("Enable", 
            typeof(bool), 
            typeof(FrameNoHistoryBehavior), 
            new UIPropertyMetadata(false, OnEnablePropertyChanged));

    private static void OnEnablePropertyChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!(d is Frame frame))
            throw new NotSupportedException($"This behavior supports only {nameof(Frame)}");

        if((bool)e.NewValue)
        {
            frame.Navigated += OnFrameNavigated;
        }
        else
        {
            frame.Navigated -= OnFrameNavigated;
        }

        void OnFrameNavigated(object sender, NavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            frame.NavigationService.RemoveBackEntry();
        }
    }
}
```